# Instagram Api: Client is no longer active

Tags: instagram

Yesterday, I was doing some test with Instagram API. I want to design a web page where I show the lastest photos in our account (Some like social feed). Today, I'm recieving this error: "The client used for authentication is no longer active.".

Somebody knows if I did some wrong working with your API and How can I do to fix this problem.

Best regards.

Thanks.

Comment: http://downdetector.com/status/instagram

Answer (score 1):

I'm running into similar issues. Have not been able to successfully pull anything through the API for over 12 hours.
Check out this link for quick API testing:

http://instagram.com/developer/api-console/

Nothing seems to work.

Comment: I keep getting 400 error for some reason. Good to know it's not just me having problems

Comment: Seems to just be the location search using lat/lon. When I use location id's it works. Not much help though since I really need lat/lon and distance in my app.

Comment: So it's seems to be https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search? that's the issue. It seems we are in the same boat. I hope they're not changing the API on us.

Comment: Exactly the same thing happening to me. No notification, no response to any reports I've made to them, no reply to tweets... nothing. I have a feeling we need to brace for a changed API. I'm getting the following message: `{"meta":{"error_type":"APIError","code":400,"error_message":"Endpoint temporarily unavailable; please retry shortly"}}`

Not shortly... ;(

Comment: Just a heads up. I just successfully called the location search endpoint. Thankfully it looks like it's back up again!