# instagram API: 400 error (APIError)

Tags: api, instagram

I tried do request from instagram API console (http://instagram.com/developer/api-console/). I use `location search` method, but I get API error in last 48 hours.

`{
  "meta":  {
    "error_type": "APIError",
    "code": 400,
    "error_message": "Endpoint temporarily unavailable; please retry shortly"
  }
}`

I want ask: I do wrong request or this's Instagram inside error?

Example request: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?lat=73.987&lng=40.756&distance=1000`

Comment: Seems to be something IG is doing  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510343/instagram-api-client-is-no-longer-active/25510890#comment39836395_25510890

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs thanks! it's awfully! :(

Comment: http://downdetector.com/status/instagram

Answer (score 1):

This is an error with Instagram. Others, including myself, are experiencing the same problem.

[image]

Comment: Seems to be happening again. Do you see anything?

Comment: Yep. Problem's been back for over 24 hours again.